# Reflection in C# for my reporting for selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, reflection

In my reporting I use:

```
  private string className = "";
    className = this.GetType().Name;
```

In order to capture the Name of the Class that I am using. Is there a similar way to access at the method level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current .net you can use `CallerMemberNameAttribute`. You can create method as follows:

```
public static string GetMethodName([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    return memberName;
}
```

Then you just call `var name = GetMethodName();` to get current method name.